# Failed to import docx on python 3.7

Tags: python, installation, docx, python-3.7, python-docx

I can't import docx on python 3.7. I have successfully installed python-docx. When I ran my code, it gave me an error: No module named 'docx'.

Thank you guys for your help in advance!!

My code looks like this (I am still working on it but I can't even clear the first hurdle which is importing docx):

```
from docx import *

document = Document('C:/Users/Vickylin/Documents/transcript')
bolds=[]
for para in document.paragraphs:
    for run in para.runs:
        if run.bold :
            bolds.append(run.text)

bold_dict={'bold_phrases':bolds}
```

Comment: can you post result of `python -m pip freeze` ?

Comment: You'll need to describe your Python environment. Usually this sort of thing is related to something like Anaconda installing libraries in a different place than the command-line Python. Btw, I recommend `from docx import Document` instead of `from docx import *`. The `Document` name is all you'll usually need and avoids polluting your module namespace with names you might want to use for something else.

Comment: This is the result of ```python -m pip freeze```: ```lxml==4.3.4
numpy==1.16.3
Pillow==6.1.0
python-docx==0.8.10```

Comment: I am running my codes on Spider on Anaconda. I tried changing to ```from docx import Document``` too. It didn't work and still gave me the same error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx'"  :(

Comment: OK, `python-docx` is installed in the `python` environment. Are you also running your code with `python`? Because you tagged your post with `python3.7`, so maybe `python-docx` is installed in the `python3.7` environment. What about `python3.7 -m pip freeze` ?

Comment: Yes, I am running my code with Python 3.7 on Spyder3 Anaconda. I tried to check ```python3.7 -m pip freeze``` but it said ```'python3.7' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.``` Don't know why...